# Queue triggers not working directly after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a (C#-based) Function App on a consumption plan that only contains queue triggers. When I deploy it (via Azure DevOps) and have something written to the queue, the trigger does not fire unless I go to the Azure Console and visit the Function App. It also works to add an HTTP trigger to the App and call that. After that, all other triggers work.

The same phenomenon is observed with Timer triggers.

My hypothesis is that these triggers only work when the runtime is active but not directly after deployment when no runtime was created. Is that true? If so, what is the suggested way around this?

My only workaround idea is to add an HTTP trigger and fire regular keepalive pings to that trigger. But that sounds wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening, but you definitely do not need to use some other kind of trigger to "keep it alive" -- that's what the queue trigger should do. I would contact Azure support if you're sure you didn't accidentally specify the wrong queue. I would also try spinning up a simple test project to try to recreate the problem.

Comment: @Slothario Thank you for the comment. The queues are ok, the App works once I visit the function in the Azure Portal. I will try to reproduce the issue with a toy project.

Comment: This is the 3th report that something is wrong with queue trigger in the past 3 days. so maybe something is actually broken :)